# Searching for a Specific character set in a table variable and Return the key

Tags: lua

I am trying to find a way to get the table key of a variable that contains a certain word

boxOfFrogs = {"hello how are you", "I am fine", "thank you"}

I have found

```
  local function has_value (tab, val)
    for index, value in ipairs(tab) do
        if value == val then
            return index
        end
    end
    return false
end
```

but that will only work if I want to search for the full variable in the table, I could not run this

```
key = has_value (boxOfFrogs, "fine")
```

well I could, but it would return "False" as there is not a key/variable in that table with just the word "fine" in it, I tried using string.match() in the function, but it errors, such as

```
print(has_value(boxOfFrogs, string.match("fine")))
```

throws:

lua: [string ""]:12: bad argument #2 to 'match' (string expected, got no value)
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'match'
[string ""]:12: in main chunk

How can I search for the key of the field that has the word "fine" in it?

Comment: Instead of `if value == val then`, use `if string.match(value, val) then`.

Comment: Instead of ```ipairs``` use ```pairs``` and your code is working then.

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi, good catch.

Comment: Of course ```string.match()``` is recommended for: "How can I search for the key of the field that has the word "fine" in it?" - Then change ```if value == val then``` to ```if value:match(val) == val then``` - Since the datatype ```string``` holds all ```string``` functions in ```__index``` ;-)

Comment: if string.match(value, val) then - works perfectly @lhf Thank you so much and for all the other answers thank you for taking the time to help me out

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi @lhf no need of `pairs` instead of `ipairs` since the table used is sequential